# calculating working hours in a month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on an attendance software in asp.net, in it i have to make a report which will tell the user about the hours and everything...so far i have created the basic functionality of the system, i.e. the user can check in and check out...i am stuck at making the report...

I have to calculate the working hours for every month, so the user can compare his hours with the total hours...what i had in mind was to create a stored procedure which when given a month name and a year, returns an int containing working hours for that month....but i can seem to get at it....

so far i found out how to create a date from a given month and a date, and found out the last day of that month, using which i can find out the total days in month...now i cant seem to figure out how do i know how much days to subtract for getting the working days.

here's the so far code..

```
declare 
@y int,
@m int,
@d int,
@date datetime


set @y = 2012
set @m = 01
set @d = 01

----To create the date first
select @date = dateadd(mm,(@y-1900)* 12 + @m - 1,0) + (@d-1) 
----Last Day of that date
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@date)+1,0))
```

any help will be appreciated guys, thanks in advance....

Comment: Be careful here.  What is the definition of a working day?  Monday-Friday?  What about part-time workers, weekend workers, bank-holidays, days where a building was closed, training days, etc, etc?  My experience suggests that your most flexible approach is to create a table that acts as a calendar - A place where you can pre-populate the number of hours that *can* be worked that day, would *normaly* be worked that day, were actually *able* to be worked that day, and were *actually* worked that day.  Then you have data rather than an algorithm, and that data can accomodate unusal circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @theDate is any date on the month you want to calculate the work days. This approach does not take care about holidays.

```
DECLARE @theDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT MONTH(@theDate) [Month], 20 + COUNT(*) WorkDays
  FROM (
         SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @theDate), 28) AS theDate
          UNION
         SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @theDate), 29)
          UNION
         SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @theDate), 30)
        ) AS d
 WHERE DATEPART(DAY, theDate) > 28
   AND DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, theDate) % 7 < 5
```

Comment: Does the answer was good enough and solved your problem? Then accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Here you can consider the below sql server code to get the first and 
last day of the given month and also ignore all the Saturdays and Sundays.

```
    DECLARE @curr_date datetime=getdate()
    DECLARE @st_date datetime,@ed_date datetime
    select @st_date=DATEADD(mm,datediff(mm,0,@curr_date),0),@ed_date = DATEADD(mm,datediff(mm,-1,@curr_date),-1)
    --select @st_date as first_day,@ed_date as last_day

    SET DATEFIRST 1 --Monday as first day of week
    select DATEADD(dd,number,@st_date) from master..spt_values
    where DATEDIFF(dd,DATEADD(dd,number,@st_date),@ed_date) >= 0 and type='P'
    and DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(dd,number,@st_date)) <> 6
    and DATEPART(DW,DATEADD(dd,number,@st_date)) <> 7

But inorder to calculate the actual working hours, you will have to take into the consideration of following thigs

1.Calculate the time interval between swipe-in and swipe-outs between start and end time for a day.
2.Exclude all the time gap(employee not in office)
3.Consider the company holidays.
 etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF to count work days. You can pass any date of a month to this function. But usually you should use actual "calendar" table to calculate work days and insert in this table weekends, holidays,... and so on.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.WorkDaysCount (@Date datetime)  
RETURNS int AS  
BEGIN 

DECLARE @BeginOfMonth datetime
SET @BeginOfMonth=DATEADD(DAY,-DAY(@Date)+1,@Date);

DECLARE @EndOfMonth datetime
SET @EndOfMonth=DATEADD(Day,-1,DATEADD(Month,1,@BeginOfMonth));

DECLARE @cDate datetime
set @cDate=@BeginOfMonth

Declare @WorkDaysCount int
SET @WorkDaysCount=0

while @cDate<=@EndOfMonth
begin
  if DATEPART(dw,@cDate) not in (1,7) SET @WorkDaysCount=@WorkDaysCount+1  -- not a Sunday or Saturday change (1,7) to (6,7) if you have other week start day (Monday).
  set @cDate=@cDate+1;
end;

return (@WorkDaysCount);

END
```